# Is there any way to exclude columns from a source file/table in Pentaho using "like" or any other function?

Tags: sql, database, pentaho

I have a CSV file having more than 700 columns. I just want 175 columns from them to be inserted into a RDBMS table or a flat file using`Pentaho (PDI)`. Now, the source CSV file has variable columns i.e. the columns can keep adding or deleting but have some specific keywords that remain constant throughout. I have the list of keywords which are present in column names that have to excluded, e.g. `starts_with("avgbal_"), starts_with("emi_"), starts_with("delinq_prin_"), starts_with("total_utilization_"), starts_with("min_overdue_"), starts_with("payment_received_")`

Any column which have the above keywords have to be excluded and should not pass onto my RDBMS table or a flat file. Is there any way to remove the above columns by writing some SQL query in PDI? Selecting specific 175 columns is not possible as they are variable in nature.

Comment: you have to follow indirect approach as non-database source has limitation. Create staging table in database and dump entire csv into it. once you have data in table you can create a query and achieve your result and put it into your target source.

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is fit to use meta data injection you can refer to example shared below

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0L0/0Y0/0K0/ETL_Metadata_Injection

two things you need to be careful

- maintain list of columns you need to push in.
- since you have changing column names so you may face issue with valid columns as well which you want to import or work with. in order to do so make sure you generate the meta data file every time so you are sure about the column names you want to push out from the flat file.